# Protractor testing: Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong with Require?

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, automated-tests, protractor, pageobjects

I'm trying to break my Protractor tests up into manageable files. 
Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong with Require?

Here is an example:

**Variables: C:/tests/variables/signInVariables.js**

```
var emailAddress = element(by.model('loginData.userName'));
var password = element(by.model('loginData.password'));
var signInButton = element(by.css('[data-auto-field="SignIn"]'));
```

**Functions: C:/tests/functions/signInFunctions.js**

```
var signInVariables = require ('../variables/signInVariables.js');

function signIn(a, b) {
    browser.get ('https://www.website.com');
    emailAddress.sendKeys(a);
    password.sendKeys(b);
    signInButton.click();
};
```

**Tests: C:/tests/protractor/conf.js**

```
var signInFunctions = require ('../functions/signInFunctions.js');

it(' should sign in ', function() {
    signIn("someusername", "somepassword");
});
```

I run it and this is what I get:

```
Failed: signIn is not defined
```

I'm sure this is a simple fix. I just don't really know what I'm doing.

Comment: I'm sure some of this logic doesn't make sense. I'm looking at it now and seeing things I've screwed up. But is the way I'm doing requires right or wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`require` doesn't quite work how you are expecting. It does not simply inline the required file the way you are using it. `require` is looking for either a JSON file, or a `module.exports` object. Here is a simple example.

require_me.js

```
module.exports = {a: "foo", b: "bar"};
```

index.js

```
var imports = require('require_me.js');
console.log(imports); // Will produce {a: "foo", b: "bar"}
```

Comment: Based on answers by @vrachlin and Brian Glaz, I read about require and modules, threw a module.exports = { }; around the variables and functions in my separate files, and reformatted my equal signs to colons and my semicolons to commas. Now it's working. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

you can read more about require and modules [here](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html), your mistake is that
signInVariables is not a module, there is no `exports` object to use.
you could do:

```
exports.emailAddress = element(by.model('loginData.userName'));
exports.password = element(by.model('loginData.password'));
exports.signInButton = element(by.css('[data-auto-field="SignIn"]'));
```

or define signInVariables as a module and export it as whole.
hope i helped.